# How to use the EditorGUILayout to create a dragable popup window?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, popupwindow

I'm currently working on a small project in Unity3D, C#, within a Custom Editor to create an NPC-script. However, I am currently stumped as to a small technique; if it even exists or no is the true question.
Right now I'm (planning on) handling dialog through the editor itself, but that'll become a humongous mess of nested-FoldOuts if I plan on doing it the way I have it in my head now.

So I came to the conclusion it would be better to have a button that opens a pop-up window that's draggable and droppable in which the player can manage his/her own dialog-hierarchy per NPC, such as shown in the following image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5z1aiil1h1xrcda/Preview.png?dl=0

It makes things look more sleak and neat, rather than stuffing everything into a single component.
So, my question is: How can I achieve this? I'm more puzzled about the window, as I am unable to find anything about it. The whole hierarchy-view is something I'll worry about on my own, as I don't want to rely too much on help from others unless it's really necessary, as it is right now.

I have looked at the documentation: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.html
but became none the wiser.

-Zubaja

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer after I posted this same question on the Unity Forums. Someone linked me to a Node Editor (http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/simple-node-editor.189230/) that seems very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I've not understood completely what you are trying to do. Anyway, if you are looking for how to create a floating dockable window (es. to use for custom tools or inspectors), you should look at [EditorWindow](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorWindow.html) class.

Inside that window you can use `EditorGUILayout` methods to layout your fields.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but someone on the UnityForums beat you to it. I was looking for something in the line of this: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/simple-node-editor.189230/ However, I will save the link for the EditorWindow you provided, as it looks quite useful.

Comment: @Zubaja: ok, glad you found a solution. Please, answer your own question and mark it as the right answer, so we can close the thread :)